# Best practices for replacing DNS server (P2V)

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I'm looking to replace a physical Ubuntu 12.04 host that serves as a DNS slave and internal resolver. It's running a very old version of BIND, runs a 32-bit kernel (and therefore is incompatible with our monitoring solution) and will soon be unable to keep up with dynamic DNS updates.

Ideally, I'd think building a new virtual machine, installing the latest OS and version of BIND and copying over bind configs of `/etc/bind` and `/var/cache/bind` would be sufficient. When the time is right, then, moving it's IP address over to this new host and decommissioning the old physical host.

Are there better practices than just making a new machine, giving it the old machine's IP and copying configs, especially as pertains to DNS?

Comment: My expierence with bind is that it is pretty simple.  Just configure the new box with the old system's IP, and copy the configs/zones/etc.

Comment: Thanks @Zoredache - I was thinking as much, but I'm always skeptical when things are simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New host on a current version of the OS. Restore configs and zones. Spot check queries to test. As this is DNS, during the cutover give it the old IP address.

Keep the old DNS server around for a short time, as a quick way to revert the change.

---

Pre-live testing and a revert plan minimize service disruption. Even if the change is less simple than anticipated.